# Huawei S5700, forwarding incoming untagged packets to bridge-domain (Error: The port has added to VLAN 1)

Tags: interface, huawei, l2vpn

Trying to forward incoming untagged packets from an AC port to a bridge-domain.
I'm following these guides:

https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100086966

https://support.huawei.com/hedex/hdx.do?lib=EDOC1100247314AEL08257&docid=EDOC1100247314&lang=en&v=02&tocLib=EDOC1100247314AEL08257&tocV=02&id=EN-US_CLIREF_0176375893&tocURL=resources%2525252Fdc%2525252Fencapsulation.html&p=t&fe=1&ui=3&keyword=encapsulation%25252Buntag

but neither **port link-type trunk** or **port link-type hybrid** issued on the main interface solve the problem of getting the following error **Error: The port has added to VLAN 1.** when trying to set the encapsulation to untag.

```
dis curr | beg Eth-Trunk0
interface Eth-Trunk0
 port link-type hybrid
 mode lacp
#
interface Eth-Trunk0.101 mode l2
 rewrite pop none
 encapsulation dot1q vid 411 to 449
 bridge-domain 100101
#
interface Eth-Trunk0.102 mode l2
 rewrite pop none
 bridge-domain 100101
[VTEP01-S5731H_24-Eth-Trunk0.102] encapsulation untag
Error: The port has added to VLAN 1.
#
```

Has anyone tried to achieve the same goal, run into this issue and found a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently the main interface on the S5700 switches must be of **hybrid link-type** and requires the following command

```
interface Eth-Trunk0
 undo port hybrid vlan 1
interface Eth-Trunk0.1 mode l2
 ...
interface Eth-Trunk0.2 mode l2
 ...
```

then the l2-mode sub-interfaces can accept either **encapsulation defaut** or **encapsulation untag** and in the last cases undergo the limits (no more than one sub.intf with untag and just one sub.intf with "default") as per documentation.

HTH